# Access a variable across multiple classes JAVA

Tags: java, class, methods

I am new to JAVA and am writing a program that passes a variable between two separate classes. I cannot seem to figure out how to send the data of a variable from one class to the other and then back? Is such a thing possible?

for example:

```
Public Class A {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the weight:");
            bagWeight=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("The total weight is: "+total);
}

Public Class B {
    double number = 3;
    public method(double number, double bagWeight) 
    {
        total = bagWeight*number;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Which class defines the variable and to which one should it go?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please try to post an example which is actually compileable?

Comment: It's called a dependency. Research "dependency injection"

Comment: I want to take the input from Class A to a method in Class B that uses it to calculate the total variable, and then display the total variable in Class A. So 2 variables, the first defined in Class A by user input, and the 2nd defined in Class B after the calculation. Maybe I'm using the wrong term, I'm new to JAVA and English isn't my first language. By variable I mean bagWeight and number, I hope I'm using that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible :D There are many ways to do so.

For example you can easily do this:

```
//Obviously pseudo Code...u need a constructor..or method
Public Class A{
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input the weight:");
            bagWeight=input.nextDouble();
            B b = new B();
            double total = b.method(1337, bagWheight);
            System.out.println("The total weight is: "+total);
    }
```